# How do dibromopyrazolones undergo base-promoted decomposition?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, heterocyclic-compounds

[image: This question was asked in my exam]

I was not sure but seeing the base as NaOH I used the fact that it will take most acidic hydrogen that is N-H and electron pair will come over it and it will resonate from two sides. I could make upto this intermediate but next I am not really sure the ring will break up and give the product as option D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although a mechanism was not reported in [Carpino's paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01536a021) of 1958, there is a more concise mechanism than the one offered by @Soumik Das. There is no need to dissemble structure **1** to a tricarbonyl compound. Vinylogous elimination of the elements of HBr from dibromide **1** leads to species **2**. [Alternatively, attack of hydroxide at the carbonyl of **1** would also suffice.] Attack of hydroxide at the carbonyl group of **2** produces **3**, which via a Grob-like fragmentation affords the propargylic carboxylate **4** of the acid **5**. ADDENDUM: The ring opening of **3** should not be construed as concerted. Just saving space.
[image]

Carpino, L. A., [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1958**, *80*, 599](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01536a021).

Answer (score 5):

In the first question, the formation of the product D) can be justified in the following way. First the reagent $\ce{OH-/H2O}$ will basically perform alkaline hydrolysis of the starting compound to form 2,3-diketocarboxylate ion. But by the hydrolysis, it will also release hydrazine ($\ce{H2N-NH2}$) in basic medium, which will ultimately perform **Wolff-Kishner reduction** on the $2,3$-diketone part of the intermidiate compound. It is interestingly observed that 1,2-diketones under Wolff-Kishner conditions always produce alkynes.

The product formation can be summarised as follows,

[image]

Also the mechanism of Wolff-Kishner reduction of $\alpha - \beta$ diketone compound is similar to the following image (Some intermidiate steps are skipped to make it concise).

[image]

The release of nitrogen gas is the main reason for driving this kind of elimination reaction forward.